# Calling C++ libraries (especially template based like CGAL) from Haskell

Tags: c++, haskell

I have been using Haskell for a few months and would really like to use it in one of my projects involving computational geometry.

Haskell however, sorely lacks in good geometry libraries. Geometric algorithms are notoriously hard to implement robustly, hence I would like to use an off-the-shelf package like CGAL. It makes heavy use of C++ templates. I won't be needing an interface to all of CGAL, just a small subset of functions which I use most of the time.

Haskell has a good C foreign function interface, but not for C++. So how can I call C++ through Haskell?

All I found was this https://wiki.haskell.org/CPlusPlus_from_Haskell which seems a complicated way of going about the process. I am sure people have a simpler way of calling C++ from Haskell.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't that there is currently a better way than what is suggested in the linked article.

Comment: It would be way amazing if there was a good interface between C++ template headers and Haskell, but alas, I doubt this is ever going to happen. I think even Python basically just uses a C interface wrapper when binding to a C++ library like CGAL; perhaps this same wrapper could be used for Haskell too.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Is it easy writing C interface wrappers for C++ libraries, be they template or non-template based?

Comment: It shouldn't be very hard if you just need a few functions.

Comment: @smilingbuddha Depends on what exactly you're trying to do. If the main feature of the library is that it's a template library, no it's not easy and probably not a good idea either. If it's just templated code in that it's generic and there's only a couple of special cases you're interested in, it's easy.

Comment: @redneb : I found very surprised (to not said less) that you have to found out and call the unmangled functions. it look crazy no ? That means there is no stability whatsoever if the lib is rebuilt.